# How to add random op in tensorflow dataset api?

Tags: tensorflow, deep-learning

I want to generate random data in a py_func op, but when I run this code, I get different random data which is expected as the same in this code.

I think the problem come with the `tf.data.Dataset.map` api. When I get the values of d5, it will run `random` function twice which d3 and d4 will get different values in this case.

Thanks.

```py
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np


def random(x):
    def random_(x):
        x = np.float32(np.random.rand())
        print("run random_")
        return x,x
    return tf.compat.v1.py_func(
        random_,
        [x],
        [tf.float32, tf.float32],
        name="generate_random")

d1 = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices(tf.zeros(10))
d2 = d1.map(random)

d3 = d2.map(lambda x1,x2: x1)
d4 = d2.map(lambda x1,x2: x2)

d5 = tf.data.Dataset.zip( (d3,d4) )

it = d5.make_one_shot_iterator()
fetch = it.get_next()
with tf.Session() as sess:
    while True:
        X = sess.run(fetch)
        print(X)
```

Answer (score 1):

As per the [documentation](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/data/Dataset#map) -

> Maps map_func across the elements of this dataset.
>
> This transformation applies map_func to each element of this dataset,
>   and returns a new dataset containing the transformed elements, in the
>   same order as they appeared in the input. map_func can be used to
>   change both the values and the structure of a dataset's elements. For
>   example, adding 1 to each element, or projecting a subset of element
>   components.

I think it’s best to see the `map` function as part of the pipeline. Every time you run `map`, nothing happens with the data yet. Instead, a chain of operations is made in the background. Note that these transformations are executed lazy. Only when you actually request data from the dataset (like with a for loop and batch), the source data from your dataset are fed through the pipeline. At that time, each `map` is applied on the image or on the batch.

As an alternative, you can fulfill your requirement as below -

**Code -**

```
%tensorflow_version 1.x
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np

def random(x):
  x = np.float32(np.random.rand())
  print("run random_")
  return x

a = []
for i in range(10):
  a.append(random(i))

d1 = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices(a)

d5 = tf.data.Dataset.zip( (d1,d1) )

it = d5.make_one_shot_iterator()
fetch = it.get_next()
with tf.Session() as sess:
    while True:
        X = sess.run(fetch)
        print(X)
```

**Output -**

```
run random_
run random_
run random_
run random_
run random_
run random_
run random_
run random_
run random_
run random_
WARNING:tensorflow:From <ipython-input-2-ee4ae8ca7ce4>:18: DatasetV1.make_one_shot_iterator (from tensorflow.python.data.ops.dataset_ops) is deprecated and will be removed in a future version.
Instructions for updating:
Use `for ... in dataset:` to iterate over a dataset. If using `tf.estimator`, return the `Dataset` object directly from your input function. As a last resort, you can use `tf.compat.v1.data.make_one_shot_iterator(dataset)`.
(0.6963448, 0.6963448)
(0.92889917, 0.92889917)
(0.054273304, 0.054273304)
(0.3719434, 0.3719434)
(0.33791015, 0.33791015)
(0.873847, 0.873847)
(0.66726416, 0.66726416)
(0.77356577, 0.77356577)
(0.4188753, 0.4188753)
(0.8886825, 0.8886825)
```

Hope this answers your question. Happy Learning.

Comment: @ye stone - Hope we have answered your question. Can you please accept and upvote the answer if you are satisfied with the answer.